# Release mode app not installed on other device

Tags: xamarin.forms

I run a Xamarin.Forms project on Release mode on my device. It's installed on my device. When I share the app to other device, the app is not installed. It shows the error like "App not installed"

Please see the logcat output here:

[image: Logcat output.]

Can any one please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Do you get any more errors?

Comment: No Bruno. When i clicked Install Button, then just i got this error.

Comment: Use logcat to check the error you are getting when installing,that could give us more insight about what's going on. I suspect you may have a problem of certificates

Comment: i run the logcat on the other device(honor 7x) and i received the message like 
attached image

Comment: Can you please check your configuration regarding your app? Like platform, linking or packages might be not generated property.

Comment: Check the phone applications, to see whether a shadow app was installed. And try to install again. Are you signing the application?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am on leave now. i will try and let you know, once i goto office.